# Fetch values from one column of a table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fatal-error

I'm trying to fetch values from one table column of a MySQL db with PHP **(PDO)**, but I have two errors in the same line, this is the line (line 7):

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
```

And these are error messages:

**Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in ... on line 7**

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ... on line 7**

My complete code:

1) file **config.php**

```
    <?php
$host = "localhost";

$db_user = "user";

$db_psw = "pass";

$db_name = "database";
?>
```

2) file **connection.php**

```
<?php

       include("config.php");

        //collegamento
    $col = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name";

        try {
                  //tentativo di connessione
          $db = new PDO($col , "$db_user", "$db_psw");
        }
                    //gestione errori
            catch(PDOException $e) {

              echo 'Attenzione errore: '.$e->getMessage();
            }      

?>
```

3) file **display-values.php *(error in line 7)***

```
<?php
// richiamo lo script responsabile della connessione a MySQL
require 'connection.php';
?>

<?php
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchall();
?>

<?php
    echo 
    "<table border='2'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>A Number</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Why</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
    <th>Signintime</th>
    </tr>"
    ;

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href=Student.php?studentA_num=" . $row['anum'] . ">" .$row['anum'] . " </a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['why'] . "</td>";  
  echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['signintime'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type=\"button\" value=\"Start Session\"onClick=\accept.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "&start=true></td>";
}

  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

Note: In this code I've tried to fetch all values (just for a test), but I need to fetch data from one column "name_column" only, so how can I fix the two errors and edit the code to extract values from a specific column?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `$db` instead of `$dbh`

Comment: You create variable `$db`, then you try to use `$dbh`... is that even your code?

Comment: I got the code from stackoverflow and I didn't see this difference... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDO object is `db` not `dbh`

The error states that:

**Notice: Undefined variable: *dbh* in ... on line 7**

PHP couldn't find an initialized variable called dbh, so *dbh* is undefined variable, therefore you have your notice here.

**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in ... on line 7**

As your code calls a method on a non existent variable, PHP is yelling this second error.

To sum up, you just need to change

`$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");`

for

`$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");`

**Editing query for fetching values from 2 columns:**

If you want to fetch values for 2 column only, just change your SQL query:

`$query = $db->prepare("SELECT column_name_1, column_name_2 FROM table_name");`

With this query you're selecting values from *column_name_1* and *column_name_2*

I recommend you to take some [basic SQL tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=basic+sql+tutorial)

Comment: Thank you! This was my mistake. ;) 

Correction on line:

`$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name");`

Comment: Now, how can I edit the code to fetch values from a specific column? Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Use `$db` instead of `$dbh`. Because in your `connection.php` you are saving the database connection link in `$db` and in your `display-values.php` you are using `$dbh`  for executing the query. So try using `$db` instead of `$dbh`.